# Effects of multiple voltage sources in a transformer

Tags: transformer

What happens to inductor di/dt when you have multiple MMF sources such as the schematic of a coupled buck converter below? Specifically when D>0.5 so M1 and M2 are overlapping.

[image: Coupled buck converter]

What I would expect is :

1. M1 turns on, increasing core B field in "positive" direction.
2. M2 turns on, creating an opposing H field
3. The opposing H field cancels the increase in B or dB/dt
4. No dB/dt means no back EMF at L1/L2 terminals, which I thought was the effect slowing down di/dt in the first place.
5. Assuming ideal components, di/dt goes to infinite.

Now obviously this does not happen, or converters such as these would not be effective. Hopefully somebody can correct my understanding.

=== UPDATE ==

A helpful comment was mentioning how higher duty cycles were dependent on leakage inductance, and attached a [document](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/28469/ETD_final_Rev2.pdf?sequence=1) explaining these issues. However the paper itself contradict this (page 20), stating that the higher coupling factor, the higher performance.

Borrowed figure 1.25 from the white paper.
[image: Figure 1.25, page 20]

Citation P.Wong:

> "From Figure 1.25, the stronger the coupling, the better the
>   performance of the multiphase coupled-inductor buck converter"

So I still feel unclear about how physically this technique works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct for the case of a perfectly coupled inductor (mutual coupling = 1 with no leakage inductance).  A coupled inductor buck converter will not work if the mutual inductance is ideal.  These converters rely on self inductance or "leakage" inductance of the coils and are wound on cores that have additional flux paths to deliberately lower mutual inductance and increase self inductance.  This makes the analysis more complex.  Try reading the introduction of: https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/28469/ETD_final_Rev2.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: Great resource. Thanks. However the linked pdf appear to contradict your statement. In chapter 2 D>1/n are analyzed, and it suggests that di/dt coupled/ non coupled is even then at its greatest when coupling reaches -1. I am still confused.